# Как отправить в сообщении название самого файла Таблицы?

Tags: google-apps-script

вашему вниманию скрипт отправки сообщений в телеграмм из таблицы, получение листов по id.  Если есть не один лист с Заказами, а два, тоесть "Заказы" и "Заказы2", то как будет выглядеть строка const swOrder = ss.getSheetByName()? и что нужно еще дописать чтобы работало должным образом? Спасибо!

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const token = 'тут ваш токен бота';
 
получаем лист по Id (start)
function getSheetById(id) { 
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(
    function (s) { return s.getSheetId() === id; }
  )[0];
}

const swOrder = getSheetById(тут id листа 'Заказы');
const swWorkers = getSheetById(тут id листа 'Штат сотрудников');
// получаем лист по Id (end)
  
// отправка в телеграмм после заполнения формы (start)
function sendTelegram() {
  let lastRow = swOrder.getLastRow();
  let workers = swWorkers.getRange(2, 1, swWorkers.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  let nameManager = swOrder.getRange(lastRow,5).getValue();
  let flatManagers = workers.flat();
  let rowManager = flatManagers.indexOf(nameManager) + 2;
  let chatId = swWorkers.getRange(rowManager, 2).getValue();
  let data = swOrder.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 5).getDisplayValues()[0];
 
  let text = `
������ ${data[1]}
☎️ ${data[2]}
ℹ️ ${data[3]}
  `
  sendText(chatId, text)
}
// отправка в телеграмм после заполнения формы (end)
 
function sendText(chatId, text) {
  let data = {
    method: 'sendMessage',
    chat_id: String(chatId),
    text: text,
    parse_mode: 'HTML'
  };
  let options = {
    method: 'post',
    payload: data
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', options)
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получение имени Таблицы

```js
const bookName = swOrder.getParent().getName();
```

получение имени листа

```js
const sheetName = swOrder.getName();
```

Пример

```js
const bookName = swOrder.getParent().getName();
const text = `
  ${bookName} ${data[1]}
  ☎️ ${data[2]}
  ℹ️ ${data[3]}`;
```